# builtins.NameError: name 'answer' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.4, nameerror, defined

This is the problem that I was getting.
I know I have to define answer globally, and I did it.
I don't know where did I do wrong.
Here is the part of code I wrote.
Please help me with this, I've just started to learn how to write code.

```
def display_puzzle_string(puzzle):
    for letter in answer:
        puzzle.append('_')
    print('The answer so far is ' +' '.join(puzzle))
```

and in `main()` I put:

```
def main():
    list_of_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango']
    answer = random.choice(list_of_words) 
    puzzle = []
    display_puzzle_string(puzzle)
```

but it came out that I have an error in my function.

```
File "/home/user/COMPUT/wp4.py", line 25, in <module>
  display_puzzle_string(puzzle)
File "/home/user/COMPUT/wp4.py", line 11, in <module>
  for letter in answer:
builtins.NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
```

I defined answer in the `def main()`, and I don't know how wrong am I, can someone help me?

Comment: `answer` is local to `main()`, it can't be accessed in other functions. Pass it as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Can you explain how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `answer` as a function parameter, since it's local to the `main()` function.

```
def display_puzzle_string(answer, puzzle):
    for letter in answer:
        puzzle.append('_')
    print('The answer so far is ' +' '.join(puzzle))

def main():
    list_of_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango']
    answer = random.choice(list_of_words) 
    puzzle = []
    display_puzzle_string(answer, puzzle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to `display_puzzle_string(puzzle)` to `display_puzzle_string(puzzle,answer)`.

And change the function definition to

```py
def display_puzzle_string(puzzle,answer):
    for letter in answer:
        puzzle.append('_')
    print('The answer so far is ' +' '.join(puzzle))
```